# Adding property to each object of an array independently with AngularJS angular.extend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I have an existing array with an object and several properties created on a first step. It is created by the following function:

```
$scope.recordlist = extractRecordJSONFromLocalStorage();
$scope.addRecord = function () {
    $scope.recordlist.push(
            {
                date: $scope.dateJson, 
                time: $scope.time, 
                car: $scope.carList.code, 
                driver: $scope.driverList.name,
                from: $scope.locationList.place,
                destination: $scope.locationList2.place, 
                pax: $scope.paxList
            }
        );

    $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
    $scope.carList = 0;
    $scope.driverList = 0;
    $scope.locationList = 0;
    $scope.locationList2 = 0;
    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};
```

It results in the following array:

```
[{
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"20.22",
  "car":"396",
  "driver":"Seb",
  "from":"A",
  "destination":"B",
  "pax":"3"
}]
```

What I'm trying to do is to add another property into the existing object on the next step with ng-click. I've tried with the following function but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$scope.insertRecord = function (recordlist) {

    var arrival = { 'arrival' : moment().format("HH.mm") }
    console.log(arrival)
    angular.extend($scope.recordlist, arrival)


    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
}
```

The end result I'm looking for is the following:

```
[{
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"20.22",
  "car":"396",
  "driver":"Seb",
  "from":"A",
  "destination":"B",
  "pax":"3",
  "arrival":"23.10"
}]
```

Maybe another thing to take also into consideration is that in the app it exists the possibility of having many different objects being listed, some that have the `arrival` property already defined, but some that will have it later in time.

Any pointers?

**EDIT**

The 2 solutions I got worked but didn't accomplish what I am looking for, so probably I was unclear on what I am trying to do.

I am saving a collection of objects into an array, each object has a property `arrival` that will be defined on a second step.

So first I create an array of objects like this:

```
[
 {
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"20.42",
  "car":"396",
  "driver":"Seb",
  "from":"A",
  "destination":"B",
  "pax":"3",
 },
 {
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"20.12",
  "car":"319",
  "driver":"Seb",
  "from":"C",
  "destination":"D",
  "pax":"4",
 },
 {
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"20.22",
  "car":"396",
  "driver":"Seb",
  "from":"G",
  "destination":"A",
  "pax":"1",
 }
]
```

This is displayed on the view in a table-like layout. Each row contains the data from an object, and initially doesn't include the property `arrival` because the app tracks car movements and the car has not arrived to destination.

Each row has also a button triggering `insertRecord()`, that defines the arrival time and its supposed to include the `arrival` property into each object, independently.

So in this example, maybe the car from the second object arrived, and I want to be able to **add the `arrival` property only for this particular object**, leaving the array like this:

```
[
 {
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"20.42",
  "car":"396",
  "driver":"Seb",
  "from":"A",
  "destination":"B",
  "pax":"3"
 },
 {
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"20.12",
  "car":"319",
  "driver":"Seb",
  "from":"C",
  "destination":"D",
  "pax":"4",
  "arrival":"20.35"
 },
 {
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"20.22",
  "car":"396",
  "driver":"Seb",
  "from":"G",
  "destination":"A",
  "pax":"1"
 }
]
```

The 2 proposed solutions from dfsq allowed me to both define arrival for the first object of the array, or for all the objects at once, but not for each object separately.

This is the HTML code where insertData is called:

```
<div class="row msf-row" ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: search">
      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.time}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><strong>{{record.car}}</strong></div>
      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.driver}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">{{record.from}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">{{record.destination}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.pax}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
           <button ng-click="insertRecord()" ng-show="!record.arrival"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button>{{record.arrival}}
      </div>
</div>
```

Being so, any hints on how to get there?

Comment: "Each row has also a button triggering insertRecord()" - then why don't you pass the object from that row to `insertRecord`?

Comment: Could you elaborate in how to do that? Thanks!!

Comment: You'd need to show that part of the HTML, the part where `insertRecord` is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If understand your question correctly you want to update a single record by adding `arrival`. Pass the record to `insertRecord`:

```
<button ng-click="insertRecord(record)" ng-show="!record.arrival">
```

There you can add the property to the respective record:

```
$scope.insertRecord = function (record) {
  record.arrival =  moment().format("HH.mm");
```

Answer (score 12):

According to your code `$scope.recordlist` is an array of objects. So you probably want this:

```
angular.extend($scope.recordlist[0], arrival);
```

**UPD** To update every object in the array you can use `map` method:

```
$scope.recordlist = $scope.recordlist.map(function(obj) {
    return angular.extend(obj, arrival);
});
```

Comment: This works! The problem is that it will always update the same object (the first), and I want to be able to update the "arrival" property object by object. What do you think?

Comment: Meaning that the first function will create an array of objects, and I want to be able to insert the arrival property in each object independently.

Comment: I updated my question as I think I was not clear enough on what I try to accomplish. Both your solutions worked, both not for what I need though. Thanks anyway mate!!