# How to add property to each object of an array in typescript.?

Tags: angular, typescript

i need to add property to each object an array . i have searched a lot , [got this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410640/adding-property-to-each-object-of-an-array-independently-with-angularjs-angular), but this is AngularJs. I have tried below but not works. Any help appreciated

```
 export class ThreeComponent implements OnInit {
 people = [];

 ngOnInit() { 
   this.people = [
   {'name': 'person 1', 'product': 'Medicine 1'},
   {'name': 'person 2', 'product': 'Medicine 2'},
   {'name': 'person 3', 'product': 'Medicine 3'},
   ]
  this.people.push({'total' : '2'})
  console.log(this.people)
  }
 }

results look like this:
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 0:{name: "person 1", product: "Medicine 1"}
 1:{name: "person 2", product: "Medicine 2"}
 2:{name: "person 3", product: "Medicine 3"}
 3:{total: "2"}
 length:4
 __proto__:Array(0)

expected result should be:
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
 0:{name: "person 1", product: "Medicine 1", "total": "2"}
 1:{name: "person 2", product: "Medicine 2", "total": "2"}
 2:{name: "person 3", product: "Medicine 3", "total": "2"}
 length:3
 __proto__:Array(0)
```

Comment: you can use an object of the array and object... `object = {people: [], total: {}}`

Comment: You question is not clear, first of all you want to add element at the end of array or beggining? Also you didn't explained what error you get, are you sure this is problem with putting object into array and not array type error?

Comment: Is my edited answer correct now ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

You changed your question completely, you should probably make a new question instead of changing the whole concept. Anyway, if you have to add new properties to your data objects, there is high chance that your app is designed wrong.

To add new property you don't use `.push()` because this is array method, instead you wanted to add new property to all objects.
You can do this by using loop for example like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.people.length; i++) {
    this.people[i].total = 2; // Add "total": 2 to all objects in array
}
```

or [array .map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
this.people.map((obj) => {
    obj.total = 2;
    // or via brackets
    // obj['total'] = 2;
    return obj;
})
```

Also, if you need to merge objects or add more unknown properties you can use loop or `Object.assign();`

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.people.length; i++) {
    // merge objects into one with multiple props
    this.people[i] = Object.assign(this.people[i], {
        total: '2', 
        someProp: 'hello', 
        likePizza: true, 
    });
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Ecma5 is compatabile for ES6 and looks like you probably don't know what you want to do.

You put your code in `ngOnInit` so be sure you call your `console.log` after this event. Your code says you called `console.log(people[1].total)` outside of your component class so it can't even access this property.

Also you should not mix different types of objects in one array - this is why typescript was made, to avoid having different things in arrays and objects.
Later in loop calling `element[i].product` can casue error becasue your new object has no such property.

```
export class ThreeComponent implements OnInit {
  people = [];
  // people: Array<YourObjects>; // would be better

 ngOnInit() { 
   this.people = [
     {'name': 'person 1', 'product': 'Medicine 1'},
     {'name': 'person 2', 'product': 'Medicine 2'},
     {'name': 'person 3', 'product': 'Medicine 3'},
   ];
   let newLength = this.people.push({'total' : '2'}); // returns new array length
   console.log(this.people[newLength ].total); // it works in this case
 }

}
```

`.push()` returns new array length what is your new element index in this case becasue `push` adds new elements at the end of array.

Comment: hope now you got my question.

Comment: Edited answer. You completely changed your question don't do like this. Before you post question think twice what you want to know. Also adding props, new elements etc is not related to typescript. Typescript just adds 'types' to your code to make it more clear, there are no additional polyfills like in babel.  Angular is framework helping to create nice js apps, your question is completely not related to typescript or angular bassicaly, its just pure js. Last thing - next time make your question clear and more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds the element to the end of the array, so you would have to access it via `people[people.length-1].total`

Comment: Add an MDN link maybe.

Comment: it should be add as a new property in all